# Run a chrome extension on specific websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a coupon style chrome extension and i want it to run only on specific websites (over 300 sites). I've read about specifying the sites url in content_scripts but that doesn't seem practical especially if i needed to update it. Here is my script:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
      "name": "Example",
      "description": "description",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "background": 
      {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js", "js/eventPage.js", "js/jquery- 
         3.2.1.min.js"],
        "persistent":false
      },

      "page_action": {
        "default_icon":"img/32icon.png"
      },

      "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "js": ["js/sites_cs.js", "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"]
        }
      ],

       "permissions": [
       "tabs",
       "http://*/*",
       "https://*/*",
       "activeTab"
     ]
    }
```

Comment: If you don't want to list all the sites in the `matches:` option, how do you want to decide whether to run it?

Comment: I want the extension to detect specific websites. When detected, if the user clicks the extension it brings them to a website for coupons

Comment: So list all the websites in `matches:`. If the list changes, update the list. I don't see any other option.

Comment: When I look at code from other coupon extensions they have `"matches": ["https://*/*"]` in there content_scripts. so there must be a way to do it in the js files

Comment: The JS may do some kind of pattern match on `window.location`

Comment: Or maybe it just checks the DOM for specific elements. The point is that the extension runs on all websites, it just doesn't do anything if there are no related coupons.

Comment: Ok, still not sure how to specify the sites i want it to "do something" on

Comment: `if (document.location.href.match(/patttern1/) { do stuff for site 1; } else if (document.location.href.match(/pattern2/) { do stuff for site 2; }` and so on

Comment: ok, i'll give this a go thanks

Comment: Extension is always running, only the content script is triggered whenever the url matches. So you could do `https://*.my-website.io/*` with the stars acting as wildcards. The pattern is `<url-pattern> := <scheme>://<host><path>`. Scheme then is `<scheme> := '*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp'`, the host `<host> := '*' | '*.' <any char except '/' and '*'>+` and finally the path `<path> := '/' <any chars>` [match_patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

Comment: matches takes an array of string..you can thus specify matches : ["pattern1","pattern2","pattern3" ..... and so on] .

Answer (score 6):

You can have an array with the URLs you want to match and programmatically inject your content scripts to the matching webpages only. For example, remove the `content_scripts` entry of `manifest.json` file and include this code in the background script:

**background.js**

```
// myURLs contains the websites where you want your content script to run
const myURLs = ['www.example1.com','www.anotherone.com','www.athird.one'];

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && myURLs.some(url => tab.url.includes(url))) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{file:'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'},()=>{
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{file:'js/sites_cs.js'});
        });
    }
});
```

This way you just need to keep the variable `myURLs` updated with the desired URLs and your content scripts will be injected only on those sites.

Comment: Thank you so much!